# Cronjob won't run properly

Tags: shell-script, cron

I have this sh script:

```
ufw allow 27017 && iptables -F
```

in a file test.sh

And I want to run this with a cronjob with root each day at 07:00 like this:

```
0 7 * * * /root/cron/test.sh
```

And I have also checked if this script actually runned with grep CRON /var/log/syslog and I can see that indeed it runned:

> Aug 24 07:00:01 vps118774 CRON[1672]: (root) CMD (/root/cron/test.sh)

Now my problem is that that actual script from test.sh didn't run properly to unblock my port runned with that cronjob, the point is that if I run that script manually from terminal on the server with:

```
sh script.sh
```

All works fine, and the script will take the desired action,so the script runs as expected but what is wrong with my cron executing that?

I put the logs of the execution got these:

> root/cron/test.sh: 2: /root/cron/test.sh: ufw: not found

Comment: You're testing your script with `sh script.sh`, but in the cronjob you run it without `sh`. If  your script was not made executable, it will fail to run. Also you should add a shebang.

Comment: Have you checked crontab owner (root I suppose) email for the output of the cron run?

Comment: @RoVo how I can make it executable from cronjob?

Comment: @andcoz I posted the output at the end

Comment: What is output of `which ufw`. Which user you add the crontab? What is `$PATH` of that user?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Cron jobs are run in a shell environment that may well be different from what your ordinary interactive shell environment is.  For example, the `PATH` variable may have a list of different directories in it and may lack some directories that you are used to being able to execute utilities from.

Figure out where the `ufw` utility is located (using `command -v ufw` on the command line), then either

1. use the complete path to that utility in the script, or
2. modify the `PATH` variable inside the script so that it includes the directory in which the `ufw` utility (and `iptables`) may be found.

The script, as shown in the question, lacks a proper `#!`-line.  This is not an issue if you run it with `sh` explicitly, but you don't do that in the cron job specification.  Instead, make the script executable and then write it as

```
#!/bin/sh

PATH="$PATH:/usr/sbin:/sbin"

ufw allow 27017 && iptables -F
```

Then call the script from your crontab exactly like you're currently doing.

Here, I've also added the two directories `/usr/sbin` and `/sbin` to the `PATH` variable, just to show how one may do that in the script.

Comment: That was it, important information for me. Thank you!